# GetResponse not a member of WebRequest in UWP

Tags: vb.net, uwp

I wrote a VB program to access information from the Web.
It works but when trying to do the same thing in UWP (Universal Windows) …
I get the following message:
 "'GetResponse' is not a member of 'WebRequest'"

Here is the code I am using less the website info.  How can this code be used in the Universal Windows Platform.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net

Module Code

    Sub SendWebRequest()

        Dim MyWebRequest As WebRequest
        Dim MyWebResponse As WebResponse
        Dim SR As StreamReader
        Dim ReadString As String

        Dim MyCache As New CredentialCache()
        Dim MyCredential As NetworkCredential = MyCache.GetCredential(New Uri("http://xxxxxx.com:xxxx"), "Basic")
        If MyCredential Is Nothing Then
            MyCache.Add(New Uri("http://http://xxxxxx.com:xxxx"), "Basic", New NetworkCredential("UserName", "UsePassWord"))
        End If

        MyWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://http://xxxxxx.com:xxxx/xxxx")

        MyWebRequest.Credentials = myCache
        MyWebResponse = MyWebRequest.GetResponse()

        SR = New StreamReader(MyWebResponse.GetResponseStream)
        Do
            ReadString = SR.ReadLine
            If InStr(ReadString, "Listen to the pronunciation of") Then
                'Do Something
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop Until SR.EndOfStream

        MyWebResponse.Close()
    End Sub
End Module
```

I updated using adding Async and Await . . . 
Run time issue at MyWebresponse = Await MyWebRequest.GetResponseAsync()
Exception User-Unandled: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'The value 'System.Net.CredentialCache' is not supported for property 'Credentials'.'

```
Async Sub SendWebRequest()
    Dim MyWebRequest As WebRequest
    Dim MyWebResponse As WebResponse
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    Dim ReadString As String
    Dim MyCache As New CredentialCache()
    Dim MyCredential As NetworkCredential = MyCache.GetCredential(New Uri("http://xxxxxx.com:xxxx"), "Basic")
    If MyCredential Is Nothing Then
        MyCache.Add(New Uri("http://http://xxxxxx.com:xxxx"), "Basic", New NetworkCredential("UserName", "UsePassWord"))
    End If
    MyWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://http://xxxxxx.org:xxxx/xxxx")
    MyWebRequest.Credentials = myCache
    MyWebResponse = Await MyWebRequest.GetResponseAsync()
    SR = New StreamReader(MyWebResponse.GetResponseStream)
    Do
        ReadString = SR.ReadLine
        If InStr(ReadString, "Listen to the pronunciation of") Then
            'Do Something
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop Until SR.EndOfStream

    MyWebResponse.Close()
End Sub
```

If someone can see what I am doing wrong above, I'd appreciate it.
In the mean time I'll try HttpClient as suggested by jmcilhinney

Comment: Is that a compilation error or a run-time exception?

Comment: Compilation Error … "GetReponse is not a member of WebRequest" is the error message

Comment: Was ok before but not when using UWP

Comment: I just pasted your code into a blank UWP app and I get the same behaviour. Looking at the members that are available, I see `BeginGetResponse` listed. I haven't worked on a UWP project yet but I do seem to recall having read that there is a focus on asynchronous programming to ensure a responsive UI. It looks like the compiler is blocking the synchronous methods and allowing only the asynchronous equivalents, so it looks like you'll have to go that way.

Comment: Actually, there's a `GetResponseAsync` method that you can call more easily with an `Await`, but [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e0423b32-3e64-41da-afe1-9ec6f76a5ed8/uwpwindows-10-universal-app-platform-webrequest-endgetresponse-platformnotsupportedexception) seems to suggest that neither might work, but it also provides an alternative.

Comment: Thanks jmcihimmey for the response.  I tried implementing the Async suggestions below but now I get a run time error at  MyWebResponse = await MyWebRequest.GetResponseAsync()

Comment: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'The value 'System.Net.CredentialCache' is not supported for property 'Credentials'.'

Comment: So, I told you that that thread suggested that those methods might not work and that it provided an alternative. Are you then surprised that that method didn't work?  Did you try the alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you should be able to change this:

```
Sub SendWebRequest()
```

to this

```
Async Sub SendWebRequest()
```

and this:

```
MyWebResponse = MyWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

to this:

```
MyWebResponse = Await MyWebRequest.GetResponseAsync()
```

[This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e0423b32-3e64-41da-afe1-9ec6f76a5ed8/uwpwindows-10-universal-app-platform-webrequest-endgetresponse-platformnotsupportedexception) indicates that that might not work though.  It does suggest an `HttpClient` as an alternative though, which would mean code something like this:

```
Dim client As New HttpClient
Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(New Uri("URL here"))

If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
    Dim data = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

    For Each line In data.Split({vbLf, vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        'Use line here.
    Next
End If
```

Note that I'm not 100% sure whether those 'vb' constants would work in UWP but I used them here for simplicity.

Comment: OK, please stop posting masses of code in comments.  As you can see, it's all but unreadable, especially if you don't format it.

Comment: As for what you tried, I specifically posted that it might not work and provided an alternative. Why are you posting to then tell me that it didn't work without trying the alternative?

Comment: It did not work as I implemented.  It was easy enough to try.  I'm looking into the httpclient now.  Thanks . . .

Comment: jmcihinney . . . Thanks for your help.  Sorry about the mess I made.  I'm still learning how to use the site.  Take Care . . .

Comment: All's well that ends well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The following does what I need in UWP.  Send a Web Request and monitor the return.
...Thanks jmcilhinney for your help

Imports System.Net

Imports System.Net.Http

Imports System.Text

Module Code

```
Async Sub SendWebRequest()
    Dim client As New HttpClient

    Dim byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("UserName:PassWord")
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = New System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray))

    Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(New Uri("http://xxxxx.xxxxxx.org:####/xxxxx"))

    If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        Dim data = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

        For Each line In data.Split({vbLf, vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            'Use line here.
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

End Module